# React- redux non re-rendering with prop change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I don't understand why react is not re-rendering after successful action and store update. I don't think I am mutating the state in my reducer as I perform all the arithmetic in my react component and then send the object trough dispatch. My react component has mapStateToProps hooked up and connect. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Below is my react component.

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) =>({


name:state.user.name,
email:state.user.email,
password:state.user.password,
skill:state.user.skill,
goal:state.user.goal,
step1:state.user.step1,
step2:state.user.step2,
step3:state.user.step3,
step4:state.user.step4,
step5:state.user.step5,
completed:state.user.completed,

})



const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  callApi: (value, state) => {


var obj = {
date:moment.tz(moment.tz.guess()).format(),
post:state.post,
email:state.email,
completed:(parseFloat(state.completed) + .75),
}

    API.addPost(obj)
    .then(function(res){
      dispatch(updateUser(res.data))
    })
  }

})
export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(YourPage);
```

My reducer

```
import {UPDATE_USER, CREATE_USER,CREATE_SKILL,CHECK_USER} from '../actions/index';


const DEFAULT_STATE =

{
createdAt:"",
name:"",
email:"",
password:"",
skill:"",
goal:"",
step1:"",
step2:"",
step3:"",
step4:"",
step5:"",
posts:[],
completed:0
}


export default function(state = DEFAULT_STATE, action) {
  if (action.error) {
    action.type = 'HANDLE_ERROR'; // change the type
  }
  switch (action.type) {


    case UPDATE_USER:



    return Object.assign({},state,{

    completed:action.payload.completed

    })
```

Comment: @Colin, are you sure about that. As far as I know, `prop` changes cause a rerender unless we do something to prevent it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check in dev tools that your store is being updated? if not check if action ever hits the reducer(add console.log to reducer) and if console.log doesn't fire, Its probably that you invoked your imported action, rather then the action with a dispatch. make sure to invoke it with 'this.props.action()' rather than 'action()' unless you destructure it.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I did check dev tools and I do see that my store is being updated. The reducer is being hit.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is elsewhere down the line

Add console.logs to check the following

1. action type constants
2. API responses
3. default case in the reducer

The code below [works properly](https://stackblitz.com/edit/redux-playground-xjfxxq?file=index.js)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { connect, Provider } from 'react-redux';
import moment from 'moment';
import 'moment-timezone';
import './style.css';

const DEFAULT_STATE = {
  createdAt: "",
  name: "",
  email: "",
  password: "",
  skill: "",
  goal: "",
  step1: "",
  step2: "",
  step3: "",
  step4: "",
  step5: "",
  posts: [],
  completed: 0
};

const reducer = function (state = DEFAULT_STATE, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'update user':
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        completed: action.payload.completed
      });
    default:
      return state;
  }
}


const reducers = combineReducers({
  user: reducer,
})

const updateUser = (payload) => ({
  type: 'update user',
  payload,
})

const API = {
  addPost: obj => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve({ data: obj }), 500))
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  callApi: (value, state) => {
    var obj = {
      date: moment.tz(moment.tz.guess()).format(),
      post: state.post,
      email: state.email,
      completed: (parseFloat(state.completed) + .75),
    }

    API.addPost(obj)
      .then(function (res) {
        dispatch(updateUser(res.data))
      })
  }

})

const store = createStore(reducers);

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log(this.props);
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => this.props.callApi(1, this.props)}>Call API</button>

        <div>Value: {this.props.completed}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  name: state.user.name,
  email: state.user.email,
  password: state.user.password,
  skill: state.user.skill,
  goal: state.user.goal,
  step1: state.user.step1,
  step2: state.user.step2,
  step3: state.user.step3,
  step4: state.user.step4,
  step5: state.user.step5,
  completed: state.user.completed,

})

const AppContainer = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);

render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <AppContainer />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: thanks for your response, I will add console logs at those places and see what I get but from what I can tell so far the proper reducer is being hit, store is being updated.

Comment: I see that the code you posted only uses redux state but what I am doing in my code is setting the local state of my component from redux state. Is there something wrong with doing that ?

Comment: it's redundant, and takes additional code to account for local state updates when app-level state changes. for derived, expensive-to-process data it's better to use `reselect`. otherwise just define more consts in render